# what data saved in cookie to identify anonymous user

Tags: cookies, session-cookies

I have an e-shopping site. I want keep anonymous user orders and if the browser is closed, When user come back to my site, I show user orders, Now what data I should save in cookie and use it to show user orders.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to send them is a sessionid. Make sure you associate sessionsIds with your orders in the db and check for the session cookie when the user request's your webpage.